# How to upload and save image without bundle in Symfony 4

Tags: image, save, symfony4, uploading

I have a user entity that has an image property. When I register a user from a registration form, the image is displayed in the user's profile view and the name of the image is saved in the database. But when I want to change the profile of the user from an edit form, when sending the form, I have the following message: the file was not found

````
 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
  * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg" })
  */
    private $picture;


     private $file;

```entity User methods

    /**
     * Get the value of file
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of file
     *
     * @return  self
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

``` the method in the AccountController

/**
     * Permet d'afficher le formulaire d'édition du profil
     * @Route("/account/profile", name="account_profile")
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function profile(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(AccountType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $user->setPicture(
                new File($this->getParameter('upload_directory') . '/' . $user->getPicture())
            );

            $manager->persist($user);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash(
                'success',
                "Les modifications ont bien été enregistrées"
            );

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user_show');
        }

        return $this->render('account/profile.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }



I also created a pictureUploadListener entity that I declared in the service.yaml file
````

Comment: I followed the symfony documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html 
I removed the unmapped file property from the user class and now I have the following error: The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File.
 would someone have a solution?

Comment: I have been looking for several days, no one has a solution to offer me?